# Align separate DIV width to equal size

Tags: html, css

This is my [site](http://azlily.bex.jp/eccube_1/html/)
On top page yu can see banner image thats `DIV class="row"`
Now below it, are two bpx `product` and `Az Lily`
But the `DIV` width is different than banner width.
I am trying to aligh all the `DIV` to equal width, But only TOP `DIV` doesnt fits in.It is bit smaller than rest of the page DIV. 
I have tried to set the width of DIV to 100%, also tried max-width to 100% 
(from other post), But no luck in vain.
I have attached the css and html of it.

```css
p.stagingsite {
    font-size: 15px;
    border: solid 2px red;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
}

.category-nav ul
{
 display:block;
}


.blockscol
{
    margin: 5px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 254px;
    float: left;
   /* border: solid 1px #eaeaea; */
    padding: 9px 9px 5px 9px;
    margin-left: 21px;
}


/*Background Header */
#header 
{
  background: url(http://azlily.bex.jp/eccube_1/html/template/default/img/background/BG.jpg) ;
}

/*Search By Keyword*/
 .input_search.clearfix 
{
    display: none;
}


/*background contend Mid Section */
#contents
{
 background: url(http://azlily.bex.jp/eccube_1/html/template/default/img/background/BG.jpg) ;
}

/*body template */

#contents_bottom {
 /*border : solid;*/
 /*background: #ffffff;*/
 /*padding-bottom: 80px;*/
 margin-top: -36px;
}

/*top Search bar*/
select#category_id {
    background: none;
}

.row_bottom {
 background: white;
 height: 480px;
 margin-top: 21px;
}

.imgcontroller
{
 float: left;
 margin: 0 33px 0 0;

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
 .imgcontroller 
    {
  margin-left: -26px;
  display: inline-grid;
  margin-left: 0 0 5px 0 ;
 }

 }
```

```html
<div id="contents" class="theme_main_only">

        <div id="contents_top">
                                            </div>

        <div class="container-fluid inner">
                                    
            <div id="main">                        
                <div id="main_middle">
                    <p class="stagingsite">Staging Site_ステージングサイト</p>
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="main_visual">
                <div class="item">
                <a href="http://azlily.bex.jp/eccube_1/html/products/list">  <img src="http://azlily.bex.jp/eccube_1/html/template/default/img/toppageimage/toppageimg.jpg"></a>
                </div>
                            </div>
        </div>
</div>



                </div>

                                                            </div>
```

Comment: Remove  div class="row"  and  div class="col-sm-12" divs above main_visual slick-initialized slick-slider div. and let me know if it works

Comment: Didnt get you.. i tried to remove `row` then move the `col-sm-12`above `main` all the screen messed up. Can u be more detail?

Comment: See my answer. you need to remove both the row and col-sm-12 divs.

Answer (score 0):

Remove row and col-sm-12 divs

```css
p.stagingsite {
  font-size: 15px;
  border: solid 2px red;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
}

.category-nav ul {
  display: block;
}

.blockscol {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 254px;
  float: left;
  /* border: solid 1px #eaeaea; */
  padding: 9px 9px 5px 9px;
  margin-left: 21px;
}


/*Background Header */

#header {
  background: url(http://azlily.bex.jp/eccube_1/html/template/default/img/background/BG.jpg);
}


/*Search By Keyword*/

.input_search.clearfix {
  display: none;
}


/*background contend Mid Section */

#contents {
  background: url(http://azlily.bex.jp/eccube_1/html/template/default/img/background/BG.jpg);
}


/*body template */

#contents_bottom {
  /*border : solid;*/
  /*background: #ffffff;*/
  /*padding-bottom: 80px;*/
  margin-top: -36px;
}


/*top Search bar*/

select#category_id {
  background: none;
}


/*.row {
 background: white;
}*/

.row_bottom {
  background: white;
  height: 480px;
  margin-top: 21px;
}

.imgcontroller {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 33px 0 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .imgcontroller {
    margin-left: -26px;
    display: inline-grid;
    margin-left: 0 0 5px 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="contents" class="theme_main_only">

  <div id="contents_top">
  </div>

  <div class="container-fluid inner">

    <div id="main">

      <div id="main_middle">
        <p class="stagingsite">Staging Site_ステージングサイト</p>

        <div class="main_visual">
          <div class="item">
            <a href="http://azlily.bex.jp/eccube_1/html/products/list"> <img src="http://azlily.bex.jp/eccube_1/html/template/default/img/toppageimage/toppageimg.jpg"></a>
          </div>
        </div>



      </div>

    </div>
```